# How do I properly import a project into ChainBuilder?

Tags: chain-builder

When I import a project into chainbuilder and re-harvest, there are still modules that are marked as "not available". The project does not run properly and some visualizations are not shown. Even the visualizations that are loading don't show the proper content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ChainBuilder exports a project it only exports the modules, their connections and settings, but not the data. Each module is identified by a unique key. While harvesting after importing a project, ChainBuilder searches the current database of services and matches services with the same key to the modules that are imported. If there are modules that dont match any service, the module will still be marked as not availabe. In this case you need to find the required services (with the matching key) and add them to the system and re-harvest again.

Since the data is not transfered automatically during the import, the workflows that provide appropriate data have to be rerun. There should be some starting points in the workflow that will reload all the data and restore the necessary datasets into the workflows and therefore also into the visualizations. See if you can find a button, textfield or dropdown-box that starts that process. Sometimes more than one button/input field will have to be triggered.